# Add other components to JFrame with canvas

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jframe, jpanel

This is my code, it will create a form with a canvas and it's working fine:

```
frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        canvas = new Canvas();

        canvas.setSize(width, height);
        canvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        canvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        canvas.setFocusable(false);

        frame.add(canvas);
```

But I want to add some spinners and checkboxes so I decided to create a `ContentPane` in the left side of the frame `(height = Frame.height , width = 100)` and then I will add my components to the `ContentPane`.

My question is: How can I add the Content Pane to the frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default a JFrame uses a `BorderLayout` for the content pane. So you can add different panels to the content pane by using code like:

```
frame.add(anotherPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
frame.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more information and working examples.

You really should use the examples from the tutorial as a starting point because they will show you how to better structure your code. For example:

1. `setVisible(true)` should be the last statement AFTER all components have been added to the frame
2. the GUI should be created on the `Event Dispatch Thread`.
3. you should not be adding AWT components to a Swing GUI. Canvas is an AWT component. Use JPanel instead.